# Mocking side effect for const pointer parameter using googlemock

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I'm using googlemock for unit tests and I try to mock a method that has an 'out array parameter':

```
void MyMock::myFunc(double myVal[2]).
```

The method myFunc is supposed to store values in the myVal array.

How do I mock this side effect? I tried the following:

```
double a_mockedValues[] = {1., 2.};
ON_CALL(myMock, myFunc(_)).WillByDefault(SetArgPointee<0>(a_mockedValues));
```

My intention is that the caller of myFunc receives the values 1. and 2. into the array that it passes to the mocked method.

However, this approach does not work. The compiler says something like:

**cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays**

Does anybody know how to mock the behavior of such a parameter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a predicate for this specific use-case: `SetArrayArgument` (see [Google Mock CookBook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-side-effects-mockingsideeffects)

Your code would then become:

```
double a_mockedValues[] = { 1., 2. };
ON_CALL(myMock, myFunc(_)).WillByDefault(SetArrayArgument<0>(a_mockedValues, a_mockedValues + 2));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I wanted. Although I get a huge compiler warning: std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe... But I suppose I could do nothing else but suppress the warning or use something else than an array.

Comment: Do you have the newest version of Google Mock? The header contains an instruction to disable this warning automatically, but only if _MSC_VER is defined. Also, please 'accept' this answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: Opps, forgot to check, sry. And yes, I could disable the warning. Thank you.